# Not able to set Simple Adapter in SherlockFragment (onPostExecute)

Tags: android

I have been trying to set `SimpleAdapter` but the app keeps crashing. I am trying to fetch values from database and show it in `ListView`. I googled and found out that in the `SimpleAdapter` we can mention context as `getActivity()` to get context of current fragment. I also found out that we can set context for a fragment, but I haven't tried that since I don't know how to set contexts of a fragment.  The code is as follows

disp.java

```
 package com.example.festipedia_logo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class disp extends SherlockFragment {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.43.77/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "price";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home2, container, false);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
        return view;

        // Get listview
        //ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
            }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    //@Override
        /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        //  Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            getActivity(), productsList,
                            R.layout.home2, new String[] {
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] {  R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.festipedia_logo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;




import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;

//@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR)
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText googlemap;
    EditText eventwebsite;
    EditText eventname;
    EditText location;
    EditText collegename;
    private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.0.103:8080/festipedia/create_product.php";

    // Declare Variables
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
    String[] title;
    //String[] subtitle;
    int icon;
    //String a= "Add Event";
    Fragment Home = new disp();
    Fragment Add = new adding();
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    static int flag=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null){
             View root = findViewById(R.id.content_layout); //find your root view
             loadTextViewState((ViewGroup)root, savedInstanceState); //load state 
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from drawer_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        //getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.fest);
        //getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.fest);
        Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        //getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(fest);
        FragmentTransaction ft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft1.replace(R.id.content_frame, Home);
        ft1.commit();
        // Get the Title
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // Generate title
        title = new String[] { "Home", "Add", "Categories",
                "Event Organisers", "Search" };

        // Generate subtitle
        //subtitle = new String[] { "Subtitle Fragment 1", "Subtitle Fragment 2",
        //      "Subtitle Fragment 3" };

        // Generate icon
        icon =  R.drawable.action_about;

        // Locate DrawerLayout in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Locate ListView in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);

        // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        // Pass string arrays to MenuListAdapter
        mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(MainActivity.this, title, 
                icon);

        // Set the MenuListAdapter to the ListView
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

        // Capture listview menu item click
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Set the title on the action when drawer open
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            //selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else if(!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
            else{ Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(this,MainActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);

            }
        }
//      else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_settings)
//      {   
//              Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Developer.class);
//              startActivity(i);
//              
//          //setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);
//      }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private String keyForTextView(TextView txt){
        return "textView"+txt.getId();
    }


    /* go through all your views in your layout and save their values */
    private void saveTextViewState(ViewGroup rootView, Bundle bundle){
        int children = rootView.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < children; i++) {
            View view = rootView.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof TextView){
                TextView txt = (TextView)view;
                if (txt.getText() != null){
                    bundle.putString(keyForTextView(txt), txt.getText().toString());
                }

            }else if (view instanceof ViewGroup){
                saveTextViewState((ViewGroup)view, bundle);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        View root = findViewById(R.id.content_layout); //find your root view of your layout
        saveTextViewState((ViewGroup)root, outState); //save state 

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
     private void loadTextViewState(ViewGroup rootView, Bundle bundle){
            int children = rootView.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < children; i++) {
                View view = rootView.getChildAt(i);
                if (view instanceof TextView){
                    TextView txt = (TextView)view;
                    String saved = bundle.getString(keyForTextView(txt));
                    txt.setText(saved); 

                }else if (view instanceof ViewGroup){
                    loadTextViewState((ViewGroup)view, bundle);
                }
            }
        }
    // ListView click listener in the navigation drawer
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        flag=0;ConnectivityManager cm;NetworkInfo activeNetwork;
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mainpageact.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Add);
            break;/*
        case 2:cm=(ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activeNetwork=cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if((activeNetwork!=null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting())==true){
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, videos);}
        else{
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, videos);flag=1;}

            break;
        case 3:
            cm=(ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            activeNetwork=cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if((activeNetwork!=null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting())==true){
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, tour);}
            else{
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, tour);flag=1;}


            break;
        case 4:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, sunday);
            break;

    case 5:
        cm=(ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activeNetwork=cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if((activeNetwork!=null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting())==true){
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, blog);}
        else{
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, blog);flag=1;}


        break;
    */
        }
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

        // Get the title followed by the position
        setTitle(title[position]);
        // Close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
           inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
           return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    private long mLastPress = 0;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Toast onBackPressedToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press once again to go to main menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (currentTime - mLastPress > 1000) {
            onBackPressedToast.show();
            FragmentTransaction ft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft1.replace(R.id.content_frame, Home);
            ft1.commit();


            // Closing all previous activities
            //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            mLastPress = currentTime;
        } else {
            onBackPressedToast.cancel();  //Difference with previous answer. Prevent continuing showing toast after application exit 
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
/*  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String Eventname = eventname.getText().toString();
        String Collegename = collegename.getText().toString();
        String Location= location.getText().toString();
        String Googlemap = googlemap.getText().toString();
        String Eventwebsite = eventwebsite.getText().toString();

        //String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eventname", Eventname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("googlemap", Googlemap));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("collegename", Collegename));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eventwebsite",Eventwebsite));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", Location));

        //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);


        final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,new home1() , "Fest Content"); 
        ft.commit();
        return null;

}*/


}
```

**EDIT** Logcat (app crashing in Sherlock fragment too)

```
03-19 20:23:59.996: E/Buffer Error(14807): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
03-19 20:24:00.011: E/JSON Parser(14807): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807): Process: com.example.festipedia_logo, PID: 14807
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807):    at com.example.festipedia_logo.disp$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(disp.java:106)
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807):    at com.example.festipedia_logo.disp$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(disp.java:1)
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807):    ... 4 more
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.festipedia_logo.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42fe6ef8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:456)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:267)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at com.example.festipedia_logo.disp$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(disp.java:89)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at com.example.festipedia_logo.disp.onCreateView(disp.java:64)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1189)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5436)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
03-19 20:24:00.436: E/WindowManager(14807):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: the question is: Why did you    commented    `//pDialog = new ProgressDialog(disp.this);`  out?

Comment: Actually I was encountering some error in that statement which I have solved now. But still my app is crashing. I have posted my updated logcat and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is
>   'android.R.id.list'

since you are extending `ListFragment` your layout should contain a ListView with id `@android:id/list`

Edit:

```
The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}
```

Since you changed from `SherlockListFragment` to `SherlockFragment`, setListAdapter is not longer available. You need a `ListView` object on which you can call `ListView.setAdapter`

Comment: please view the edit section I have added the xml file which I am setting as the layout. The list view in this xml has id 'list'

Comment: it should be `android:id="@android:id/list"` . Please read the answer provided

Comment: I have added another edit wherein the class uses SherlockFragment instead of SherlockListFragment along with the error I am facing... Please help

Comment: I just tried this out. The error states : `The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type disp`

Comment: I fetched the list view from the xml and wrote the following code:
`l.setListAdapter(adapter);`
The error states:
`The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type ListView`

Comment: because it is setAdapter .

Comment: The app is crashing again. But I don't know what's the reason. I am posting the edited logcat

Comment: disp.java line 106. Which one is it?

Comment: The line is: `int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);`
BTW how were you able to find the line no?

Comment: you have to learn to read the stacktrace: `03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 20:24:00.021: E/AndroidRuntime(14807):    at com.example.festipedia_logo.disp$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(disp.java:106)` . That means that json returned is null